# How to know if user has passed from particular location or missed the location

Tags: java, android, location, latitude-longitude, marker

[image]

How to check if the user has crossed latitude:37.6511 and longitude -122.4142(check image) or missed this latitude longitude by going in another direction(deviated).

Comment: You might want to look into Geofencing

Comment: More details: [https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing)

Comment: However geofencing isn't enough for telling if the user is traveling to the wrong direction. But if you have the target location and constant updates on the user's location you can calculate the direction towards the target location and the direction the user is moving into and compare those.

Answer (score -1):

You should use geofences for that developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing